# storing and removing data in a simple way

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website where the user can choose differente options from a database. Lets say I have a database with animals. And the user can choose different animals. I am using AJAX to get the data, so my page do not reload for every new headline.

So the user finds animals under the headline "Brown animals" and selects "kittens" by checking the checkbox. And the user keep searching and under the headline "Cute Animals", "Kittens" once again comes up. Then "Kittens" should be checked because the user checked it before. After searching through many headlines and different animals the user can submit it.

My question is how can I do this? I was thinking of adding every Id for each animal in a input. Like this `<Input type="hidden" value="1,4,7,14,34,192">` but realized the problem by remove an element if the user wanted to do that.

Is there any other way I can do this?

**EDIT (Clarifying):**
I am using ajax to get the records from a database. And the databse consists of many thousands rows of animals. I am sending an Ajax-request, with the parameters, eg. ?cute=1&color=brown&wild=1&vegetarian=1 and so on. And depending on the parameteres it prints out the right animals. And when it prints out the new animals, you may experience that one animal is coming up a second time (even if I selected it the first time), and if that is the case it should be a selected option.

So if I selected Kitten under "Cute animals" and I make a new search for "Brown colored", and Kittens again comes up, it should be selected.

Comment: Consider looking into a framework that supports data binding, like [angularjs](https://angularjs.org/)

Comment: From a UX point, you may want a way to display all the checked options so the user knows exactly what they are submitting. A form like that could also be responsible for storing the data.

Comment: @fqhv Yes, I would really like to display all the checked options, how can a form like that be responsible for storing data? Are you thinking of a regular  HTML-form?

Comment: @Danny I am looking into Jquery. Maybe I can find something like that in that framework?

Comment: @william82 jquery makes js easy, angular makes data modells easy...

Comment: @William82 no, jquery wouldnt handle that for you. here is a simple proof of concept of what i think you are trying to accomplish. https://jsfiddle.net/e4yxn9v7/

Comment: @Danny Yes, sort of. But I am using ajax to get the data. So in that case I have to print out many thousands rows of animals. 
Because I am sending an Ajax-request, with the parameters, eg. ?cute=1&color=brown&wild=1&vegetarian=1 and so on. And depending on the parameteres it prints out the right animals. And when it prints out the new animals, you may experience that one animal is coming up a second time (even if I selected it the first time),  and if that is the case it should be a selected option.

Comment: You can use ajax to request the data here too. Look at my comment about using `$http`. `$http` is a service that angular provides to do ajax requests.

Comment: @William82 https://jsfiddle.net/e4yxn9v7/1/ does that do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way: 
Every animal/checkbox have an Id. And when I select the option I call the function addanimal(id). Then it writes the number inside a hidden input. 
When it gets deselected, it replaces the number with ''.

```
function addanimal(id){

if (document.getElementById("animal" + id).checked){
    document.getElementById("selectedanimal").value = document.getElementById("selectedanimal").value + " " + id + ", "; 

} else {
    document.getElementById("selectedanimal").value = document.getElementById("selectedanimal").value.replace(' ' + id + ',', '')
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that I get your question correctly; but probably you can store your informations into localStorage.

For a full documentation of localStorage (or sessionStorage) please have a look here : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Since it is all on one page that is just updated via AJAX, there is no need to use localStorage -- js variables can maintain the selections.

Comment: Except That you loose this memory if you reload the page With JS, not localstorage

Comment: You are correct, but OP specifically states _"I am using AJAX to get the data, so my page **do not reload** for every new headline"_, and with localStorage you'll have to program for the case where a user is newly arriving at the page after some previous visit, and you may need to clear out the old selections from localStorage.  Now if you _want_ to remember the past selections then I agree localStorage is the way to go. (aside: it's "lose" not "loose")

Comment: typo issue from my phone ;) totally agree with your statement. @StephenP

Comment: @StephenP How can I use js variables? Can I remove a chosen element?

Comment: Can I use Javascript objects? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: Yes you use That Kind of objects

Comment: Why have I been Downvoted ? !!! my reply; even if it s not perfectly what is the owner wanted; is not wrong and without sense !